# sqlalchemy one-to-one relation real example

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a novice in sqlalchemy. I read a lot of guidelines but failed to reproduce it.
I Need to make relation 1-to-1 and I'm failed (every user has a related meta table to distinguish between data and info).
This is my current broken code.

```
class UserData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    age = Column(Integer, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String, index=True)
    last_name = Column(String, index=True)
    country = Column(String, index=True)
    city = Column(String, index=True)
    comment = Column(String, index=True)
    users_meta = relationship("UserMeta", uselist=False, back_populates="users")


class UserMeta(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_meta"

    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    users = relationship("UserData", back_populates="users")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is almost correct, it needs two changes:

1. `UserMeta` needs a primary key column

   ```
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
   ```
2. The relationship definition in `UserMeta` should refer to `UserData`'s `users_meta` attribute, not `users`, which does not exist.

   ```
    users = relationship("UserData", back_populates="users_meta")
   ```

One minor point - there's no need for `index=True` in `UserData.id`, primary keys will be indexed automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer a few more questions for me?
1. Why need a relationship at all, in standard SQL there only foreign key?
2. What names for FK and relations I must use in this code? because I'm don't know the answer to the first question, I'm don't know what names to use. I'm currently just using names of parent/child/method of tables.

Comment: For example: `class UserData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_data"
    ...
    users_meta = relationship("UserMeta", uselist=False, back_populates="users_data")


class UserMeta(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_meta"
    ...
    user_data_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users_data.user_id'))
    users_data = relationship("UserData", back_populates="users_meta")`

Comment: Relationships provide more information that the FK - for example relationships can describe many to many relations, which may not be deducible from FKs alone.  And they can describe other Python-level configuration, such as the type of collection used for the many side(s), or the whether FKs are loaded with their parents or later.  You can name them anything you like.  Parent/child is fine.